# What's the best way to get a list/array of element-wise means between an array and a constant?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

Suppose I have `my_array = np.array([2, 4, 6])` and I want to get another array that represents the mean of each element in `my_array` and a constant, say, 2. So I want to return `returned_array = [2, 3, 4]`. What is the best way to do this?

When I try `np.mean(my_array, 2)` I get `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

I can create my own mean function for this purpose:

```
def mean(a,b): 
    return (a+b)/2
```

and this works fine. This is obviously not an ideal way to do this. What is the best way? Why must everything in numpy be an ordeal?

Comment: I can't tell what you mean here.  If you wanted the mean of each element and a constant, then the output matrix would be the same size as the input matrix, and for that you could literally do `(my_array + 2) / 2`.  Why does the size reduce?  Perhaps you should show an example.

Comment: "This is obviously not an ideal way to do this" What is particularly not ideal?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did. Everything is in the example I gave. My input/variables, my attempted operations, the output I received. I don't know what more you want.

Comment: Also, that isn't the error produced by `np.mean(my_array, 2)` for me, what version of numpy are you on?

Comment: @NaiveBae I misread your question, I thought you were saying that the function you defind was producing that error.

Comment: I'm using v.1.21.6. It didn't seem ideal to me because I figured there had to be a way of doing it without defining my own mean function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([2, 4, 6])
other = 2
(my_array + other) / 2
# [2. 3. 4.]
```

It's just the element-wise average of two numbers, which is the same as just dividing by two.

Comment: That's it. Clever. I was trying to use np.mean.

Comment: @NaiveBae is this not the exact same thing as : `return (a+b)/2`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is. this question is so confusing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is the same thing as `return (a+b)/2`. It got me what I needed without having to define my own mean function. That's why I accepted it as the answer. Idk why everyone is confused lol.